# Using Boost Graph Library on Mac Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I have a similar question regarding using Boost under Windows.  I'm very new to Boost and I just installed the Boost library on my Mac, I'm interested primarily in the Boost Graph Library.  My questions are as follows, when installing Boost by default on my Mac, is the BGL installed automatically as well? I ask this because the Boost website talks about the BGL being a header-only library that does not need to be built.  My next question is, how do I access the BGL and use it in Eclipse on Mac?? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the Boost Graph Library on Windows and on several Unix flavors, but not on Mac. But I think my comments are relevant nevertheless.

You are confusing the library being *installed* with the library being *built*. When you installed Boost on the Mac, the BGL is also "installed", in the sense that the BGL headers are copied the Boost's include directory.

In order to use the BGL you do not have to build and link to a library or dll (or whatever they are called on Mac). All the code is in these header files, and will be pulled into your code when you #include it.

As to eclipse. I do not know.